# Delete project from vs 2010 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to permanently delete a project from a vs 2010 solution ? 
Right Click->Remove removes it from the solution, but does not physically delete it.

If you know of any extension that can do this let me know also -

Thanks

Comment: The extension is called "source control".

Comment: what does "source control" have to do with my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only remove the project from the solution.  You need to use Windows Explorer to delete it permanently.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ba7zx39%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the how-to.

Comment: ; and the reason for this is to make sure you don't permanently accidentally delete an entire project.

Answer (score 0):

its worth noting that I tried to remove from VS2010 and delete from folder and that caused major problems when i wanted to create a new project with the same name. I would recommend unloading the project first from vs2010 before deleting/removing